# askWithList with RichResponse. What to use instead?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm using the Actions SDK and I'm trying to implement the following interaction (devices with screens only), but I have not been successful so far:

```
Here are your top 3 songs. Select one you like or say 'show me more' to see the next 3 songs.

 * Song 1: X
 * Song 2: Y
 * Song 3: Z

> Show me more

Ok, here are 3 more songs. Select the one you like or say 'Show me more'.

 * Song 4: S
 * Song 5: T
 * Song 6: U

> Song 4: S

Ok, here's information on Song 4. Tap on the link to go to the artist's website:

[title]
[album image]
[link to https://www.example.com/album/song]
```

If I use `askWithList` and handle the `actions.intent.OPTION` intent, the helper ignores any lists or basic cards in the response. This seems to be by design, based on the comments on [this page](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#richresponse):

> Cards may not be used if an actions.intent.OPTION intent is used

How can I implement this interaction? 
How can I show a link as a result of a list item being selected?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Edit: just to clarify, there are 2 issues here:

1. When the user selects an item from a list, it is not possible to show another list
2. When a user selects an item from a list, it is not possible to show a basic card.

If you disagree with 1 or 2, please provide evidence.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the issue here is. It seems like you're using askWithList() properly to show lists of options, and when the user selects one (incoming request has actions.intent.OPTIONS intent), you are sending back a Rich Response w/ a Basic Card (using ask() I assume). There should be nothing wrong with this.

Comment: The issue is that when the user says "Show me more" it is impossible to show another list. "There should be nothing wrong with this" - the issue is this does not work. I'd love to see an example where it does work.

Answer (score 0):

While the basic card resulting from a Carousel or a list options won't show on the simulator, it will work fine on mobile devices.

Comment: I have tried it with my own device and it does not work. Please provide an example if you are certain it does, because what you're saying goes against Google's documentation.